# responsive grid layout rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app that generates a grid layout in the view. I have it slice 6 items from the instance variable and add them to a bootstrap row - and then repeat. The reason I do this is because inside each row is another row that is shown when an item is clicked.

I now want to make it show only 3 movies on a phone and 6 on a laptop - but I think the only way is to remove the row and just use bootstrap cols to position the items - and then dynamically create a div under the clicked item. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a media query to hide 3 of them on a mobile? You could do something like

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .movie:nth-child(4),
    .movie:nth-child(5),
    .movie:nth-child(6) {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I hide them - I'm hiding 1/2 of my content. Idealy I'd want the 3 to wrap onto the next row - but that would mess up the drop down info row that appears when you click. 

I think what I'd need to do is use bootstrap cols so that I get 6 on md screens and 3 on xs - and then just add a row below when clicked instead of having the row there in the html.

Comment: Ah, yeah that makes more sense... Sorry I misunderstood when you said 'I want to show 3 on a mobile and 6 on a laptop'